# Gather_Nd error when fine-tuning EfficientDet on a custom dataset on Google Colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

I'm trying to fine tune EfficientDet on a custom dataset using Google Colab (free) for multi-object detection.
I'm new to tf so I tried to reproduce/modify an existing notebook (this one: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1iOydvFQVE-syG-ixEyam04X3E40Lx7NA?usp=sharing)

Here is the problem.
When training i get the following error:

```
(0) Invalid argument: indices[2] = [2] does not index into param shape [1,1], node name: parser/GatherNd_1
     [[{{node parser/GatherNd_1}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]]
     [[IteratorGetNext/_4303]]
```

Cannot get where that comes from, eventhough I'm aware that it could come from the TFrecord files.
My train dataset is made of png images (resized to size 256x256) and associated metadata for bounding boxes. Here's how I generate the tfrecord files:

```
def create_tf_example(filepath, df_label):

    encoded_image_data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
    key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_image_data).hexdigest()
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    image_name = filename.replace(".png", "")
    height0 = df_label["height0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]
    width0 = df_label["width0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]
    image_format = b'png'
    width = 256
    height = 256

    xmins = [x / width0 for x in df_label["xmins0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]]
    xmaxs = [x / width0 for x in df_label["xmaxs0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]]
    ymins = [x / height0 for x in df_label["ymins0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]]
    ymaxs = [x / height0 for x in df_label["ymaxs0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]]
    classes_text = ["opacity".encode("utf-8")]
    classes = [1]

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[height])),
        'image/width': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[width])),
        "image/filename": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[filename.encode("utf-8")])),
        "image/source_id": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=['0'.encode("utf-8")])), # Pb with image names solved with this hack
        "image/key/sha256": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[key.encode("utf-8")])),
        "image/encoded": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[encoded_image_data])),
        "image/format": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=["png".encode("utf-8")])),
        "image/object/bbox/xmin": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=xmins)),
        "image/object/bbox/xmax": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=xmaxs)),
        "image/object/bbox/ymin": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=ymins)),
        "image/object/bbox/ymax": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=ymaxs)),
        "image/object/class/text": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=classes_text)),
        "image/object/class/label": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=classes)),
        }))
    return tf_example

writer_train = tf.io.TFRecordWriter('/content/drive/MyDrive/siim-covid19-detection/TFRecords/train/train.tfrecord')

for filepath in train_filepaths:
    tf_example = create_tf_example(filepath, df_train)
    writer_train.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())

writer_train.close()
```

Same code for val.tfrecord.

I downloaded the model with this:

```
if not os.path.isdir("automl"):

    !git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/google/automl
    %cd automl
    !git checkout f2b4480703278250fb05abe38a2f4ecbb16ba463 # Recent commit

    %cd efficientdet

    %pip install -r requirements.txt
    %pip install -U "git+https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI"

MODEL = "efficientdet-d0"
if not os.path.exists(f"{MODEL}.tar.gz"):
    !curl -O https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-tpu-checkpoints/efficientdet/coco2/{MODEL}.tar.gz
    !tar xvzf {MODEL}.tar.gz
```

Config is this:

```
PROJ_DIR = "/content/MODEL"
CONFIG_DIR = os.path.join(PROJ_DIR, "configs")
CONFIG_FILE = os.path.join(CONFIG_DIR, "default.yaml")
if not os.path.exists(CONFIG_DIR):
    os.mkdir(CONFIG_DIR)

config_text = \
"""image_size: 256x256 # this is the size of my images
num_classes: 1
label_map: {1: opacity}
input_rand_hflip: true
jitter_min: 0.8
jitter_max: 1.2
"""

with open(CONFIG_FILE, "w") as fwrite:
    fwrite.write(config_text)

TFRECORD_DIR = "/content/drive/MyDrive/siim-covid19-detection/TFRecords"

CKPT = MODEL

TRAIN_SET = os.path.join(TFRECORD_DIR, "train/train.tfrecord")
VAL_SET = os.path.join(TFRECORD_DIR, "val/val.tfrecord")
MODEL_DIR_TMP = os.path.join(PROJ_DIR, "tmp", f"{MODEL}-finetune")
TRAIN_NUM_EXAMPLES = len(train_filepaths)
EVAL_NUM_EXAMPLES = len(val_filepaths)
EPOCHS = 2
BATCH_SIZE = 16
```

And here's how I start the training:

```
!python -m main \
    --mode=train_and_eval \
    --train_file_pattern={TRAIN_SET} \
    --val_file_pattern={VAL_SET} \
    --model_name={MODEL} \
    --model_dir={MODEL_DIR_TMP} \
    --ckpt={CKPT} \
    --train_batch_size={BATCH_SIZE} \
    --eval_batch_size={BATCH_SIZE} \
    --num_epochs={EPOCHS} \
    --num_examples_per_epoch={TRAIN_NUM_EXAMPLES} \
    --eval_samples={EVAL_NUM_EXAMPLES} \
    --hparams={CONFIG_FILE}
```

Thanks in advance for your help !

Comment: Could you please share the Colab you used and/or the full stack trace?

Comment: Hi Allen, thanks for your reply.
Here is the link : https://colab.research.google.com/drive/11evjgpoaxqfwLB1Kl97kWKxWlrXqf1st?usp=sharing

Comment: Thanks for sharing the Colab! I'm not sure where exactly the error comes from, but here's a good hint:
```
INFO:tensorflow:Loss for final step: 0.97554517.
I0617 20:25:41.305148 140287598352256 estimator.py:350] Loss for final step: 0.97554517.

   =====> Starting evaluation, epoch: 1.
```
so basically training epoch 1 is successful but the error only comes when we evaluate. I'd check if you did something different for eval, maybe it comes from [here](https://github.com/google/automl/blob/d8f4c240e593410ff8b0932597c395203b65ab2d/efficientdet/dataloader.py#L189-L190)?.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Allen ! It seems to be a good hint indeed... I'll check that out and let you know if this solves my problem.

Answer (score 0):

All right, I found my error:
the number of classes and classes texts did not match the number of bbox for a sample in a tfrecord file. I changed the code like this and it did the trick:

```
def create_tf_example(filepath, df_label):

    encoded_image_data = open(filepath, "rb").read()
    key = hashlib.sha256(encoded_image_data).hexdigest()
    filename = os.path.basename(filepath)
    image_name = filename.replace(".png", "")
    height0 = df_label["height0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]
    width0 = df_label["width0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]
    image_format = b'png'
    width = 256
    height = 256

    xmins = [x / width0 for x in df_label["xmins0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]]
    xmaxs = [x / width0 for x in df_label["xmaxs0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]]
    ymins = [x / height0 for x in df_label["ymins0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]]
    ymaxs = [x / height0 for x in df_label["ymaxs0"].loc[df_label["id"]==image_name].iloc[0]]

    classes_text = ["opacity".encode("utf-8")]*len(xmins) # now it creates a list of strings with length equal to the number of bbox
    classes = [0]*len(xmins) # now it creates a list of int with length equal to the number of bbox

    tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
        'image/height': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[height])),
        'image/width': tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[width])),
        "image/filename": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[filename.encode("utf-8")])),
        "image/source_id": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=['0'.encode("utf-8")])), # Pb with image names solved with this hack
        "image/key/sha256": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[key.encode("utf-8")])),
        "image/encoded": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[encoded_image_data])),
        "image/format": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=["png".encode("utf-8")])),
        "image/object/bbox/xmin": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=xmins)),
        "image/object/bbox/xmax": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=xmaxs)),
        "image/object/bbox/ymin": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=ymins)),
        "image/object/bbox/ymax": tf.train.Feature(float_list=tf.train.FloatList(value=ymaxs)),
        "image/object/class/text": tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=classes_text)),
        "image/object/class/label": tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=classes)),
        }))
    return tf_example
```